# Get data from stdClass Object

Tags: php, json, object

Hi I want to get the name in this objects how can I get these names for each stdClass.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [page] => 0
    [items] => 10
    [programItems] => stdClass Object
        (
            [programItem] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@id] => 8955
                            [name] => name
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@id] => 8955
                            [name] => name1
```

I get this data with

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http:/example.com"));
```

Comment: @Uchiha Why would you want to convert a perfectly good Object into an array. _Does not compute_

Comment: Yeah you're right @RiggsFolly I might be wrong at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick :

```
$programItem = $data->programItems;

foreach($programItem as $item){
  echo $item->name;
}
```

Comment: $programItem = $data->programItems->programItem; 
  foreach($programItem as $item){
     echo $item->name;
 }                                                                                                                        This did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Considering `$arr` has the std object data,

```
$arr->page;
$arr->items;
foreach($arr->programItems as $a){
     foreach($a as $b) {
        echo $b->name;
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your will get the json data in $stdobj

```
$stdobj=json_decode(file_get_contents("http:/example.com"));
                    echo "Page = ".$stdobj->page."<br>";
                    echo "item = ".$stdobj->item."<br>";
                    foreach ($stdobj->programItems as $datas) {
                        foreach ($datas as $data) {
                            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                                echo 'key = ' . $key . ', value :' . $value . '<br/>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
```